# Recommended Books in Euler Function Calculation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, book-recommendation

I'm studying in Number Theory, but most of problems is about remainder calculation, for example:

> Use Euler Theorem to find the remainder upon division of $2016^{{2015}^{2014^{...}}}$ by $11$.

I need a problem book of this kind of exercise. Is there any book like this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are the dots in your exponent ? Is it more than a tower of 3?

Comment: It's just an example. I just need a book recommendation.

Comment: Most books on elementary number theory cover this. Hardy and Wright is considered as a classic. But Dirichlet's Vorlesung uber Zahlentheorie is a masterpiece of exposition.